# On clicking UIButton while animating its title background shows bugged behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiviewanimationtransition

Trying to fix the background of the button's title. And here it happens while transitioning from blue.png to green.png when I click the button the background of the title of the button takes the blue.png while button takes green.

Here the whole button should show same green.png 
And when I remove `UIView.transition` it works good.

```
@IBOutlet weak var option_1: UIButton!

func optionsAnimateGreen(){  
  let options = [option_1]
  let stop = [stop_1]
  for (option, stopper) in zip(options, stop){  //loops options and stop
    let btn:UIButton = option!
    if stopper{
      UIView.transition(with: btn, duration: 1.5, options: [ .transitionCrossDissolve, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        btn.toggleSelection()
      }, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}


self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.optionsAnimateGreen), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);


extension UIButton {

    func toggleSelection() {
        self.isSelected = self.isSelected ? false : true
    }
}
```

[image: the bugged UIButton]

In xib viewcontroller: The default state of button background is set to blue.png and for selected state of button background is set to green.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the UIButton type from "System" to "Custom" in your Storyboard/XIB. What you see is a default behavior from a System button in a SELECTED state.

The transition is not the problem, the problem is when the button get selected "button.isSelected = true"

Comment: This works like a charm. I have been struggling to find what was the problem. Thanks.